how can i uninstall **ALL** the non-windows drivers permanently without data loss in windows 11
After experimenting with various driver installations on my laptop, I've ended up with numerous options for a single device in the device manager. How can I efficiently uninstall all the non-Windows 11 clean install drivers? I aim to then install the latest drivers available from the vendors' websites. Are there any applications, scripts, or codes that can assist me in this process?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Probably the best you can do is start with a clean Windows installation and then install the latest drivers without further "experiments". What you reported - multiple entries for the same device - isn't normal and may not be related with drivers installations. For most drivers the installer merely updates the existing ones.

Only way to do so is via SysPrep /Generalize, and since it removes all user data, it's more efficient to clean install. When clean installing, the CPU chipset drivers must be installed immediately upon exiting OOBE when you're at the Desktop, as they must be installed prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates. Reboot, then configure Windows Update to install drivers, run Windows Update, rebooting and repeating until no updates are left, then install software.

I am confused. All drivers that can be installed in Windows are Windows drivers. If you know the .inf file of the driver it’s trivial to uninstall drivers. So what exactly is a non-Windows driver?

The easiest for me is to use DISM in CMD prompt to list all drivers, then PNPUTIL to uninstall specific drivers. See https://www.elevenforum.com/t/uninstall-driver-in-windows-11.8651/ . Blindly uninstalling all non-MS drivers could leave the machine unusable.
